# PHP file errors

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've got an html file that creates a form that links to a php file and allows a multi-parameter search of a database.  For whatever reason, the file isn't reading and I'm getting an error, making it difficult to test my sql query and verify that it works.  Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"

"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
<head>

<title>Bicycle Store Employees</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="web.css" />

</head>
<body>

<h1>Bicycle Store Manager</h1>

<h2>Customized Business Management for Bicycle Stores</h2>

<h3>EMPLOYEE INFORMATION</h3>

<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

$mysqli = new mysqli("$database", "$username", "$password", "$username");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {

print "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;

}
if( $_POST["submit"] ) {

    if (!($stmt =$mysqli->prepare("SELECT * into tempTable FROM 
(SELECT Fname, Minit, Lname, Address, Hourly, Sname, Saddress, Dno
FROM EMPLOYEE
join on Employee.Dno = DEPARTMENT.Dnumber
join on LOCATION.Store_num = DEPARTMENT.Store_num
where Fname = $_POST['Fname'] OR Lname = $_POST['Lname'] 
OR Stor_num = $_POST['Store_num'] OR Dno = $_POST['Dno']
GROUP BY Store_num);"))) {

print "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
if (!$stmt->bind_param("ssii",$_POST['Fname'], $_POST['Lname'], $_POST['Dno'], $_POST['Store_num'])) {
print "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
if (!$stmt->execute()) {
print "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
 $stmt->store_result();

if (!$stmt->bind_result($Fname,$Minit,$Lname,$Phone,$Address,$Slocation,$Saddress,$Dno,$Hourly)) {
    print "Binding output parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
if ($stmt->num_rows == 0){
print "No results were found for the following search <p>"
  .$_POST['Fname'].$_POST['Lname'].$_POST ['Store_num'].$_POST['Dno']."</p>";
    }
else {
print "<table border=2 cellpadding=4>

        <tr bgcolor=white>

        <th>First Name</th>

        <th>Middle Initial</th>

        <th>Last Name</th>

        <th>Phone</th>

        <th>Address</th>

        <th>Store</th>

        <th>Store Location</th>

        <th>Dept #</th>

        <th>Hourly Rate</th>

        </tr>";

    while ($stmt->fetch()){

        print "<tr><td>".$Fname."</td><td>".$Minit."</td><td>".$Lname.

        "</td><td>".$Phone."</td><td>".$Address."</td><td>".$Slocation."</td>

        <td>".$Saddress."</td><td>".$Dno."</td><td>".$Hourly."</td></tr>";

    }

    print "</table>";
}

$stmt->free_result();
}

$mysqli->close();
?>


<p><a href="employee_info.html">SEARCH AGAIN</a></p>

<p><a href="index.html">HOME</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and what's the error...?

Comment: Please post the error message.  Please also identify the line in your code that's causing the error.

Comment: It's hitting the connect_errno error and printing "Failed to connect to MySQL", etc followed by a display of all my php code to the webpage.  I have verified that the database, username, and password are all correct.

Comment: That's understandable. You have empty variables in your connection string.

Comment: They're not empty.  I took out that portion of code to protect my username and password

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a Look.

[mysqli_error,mysqli::$error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("$database", "$username", "$password", "$username");
```

First of all, you don't have to enclose the variables in double quotes.

So, it would be like this:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($database, $username, $password, $username);
```

And also, where is the values for the variables `$database`, `$username`, `$password` and `$username` defined ? You should set the values prior to using it !

Comment: As I said above, I've removed my username and password from the code.  In reality, they are inside the quotes.

Comment: If you are hardcoding the values, then only you need to enclose the values in double/single quotes. Otherwise, just pass the variables only. Also, next time when you post questions like this, and if you have taken down these values to protect it, then please mention it in initial post itself. Or just include the variables, and then mask them. Say, use `***` or `xxxx` as values. Thank you.